# Is it possible to contain duplicated ids in calculation with IN() statement - TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am working on an SP that gets the sold product ids as comma separated string as an input.

***Restrictions***:

- Cannot add a new input
- Cannot change the input datatype

I have a function that gets the inputted comma separated string and returns a table including a row for each id.

```
SELECT * FROM SplitStringIDsIntoTable(@ProductIDs,',')
```

Then to be able to calculate the cost of good of each sold item (if the item sold 3 times, I need to add its COG 3 times and unfortunately it is out of question to get a new input that tells me the quantity for each sold item), I was doing something like:

```
SET x = (SELECT SUM(p.COG) FROM Products p WHERE p.ProductId IN 
    (SELECT * FROM SplitStringIDsIntoTable(@ProductIDs,',')))
```

But the problem here is, I do not have the quantity as input.
When I use IN() statement, it counts each id ONLY once as expected.

For instance lets say my sold product ids inputted as '11,12,13,11,13'

My sql statement would be:

```
SET x = (SELECT SUM(p.COG) FROM Products p WHERE p.ProductId IN 
        ('11,12,13,11,13'))
```

which returns exact same result with :

```
SET x = (SELECT SUM(p.COG) FROM Products p WHERE p.ProductId IN 
        ('11,12,13'))
```

which does not give the correct total.
What I am looking for is, is there any statement that takes duplicated values into consideration as well?

I do not want to use While Loop.

PS: I am not sure how to ask this question in title, so question title may look meaningless. Feel free to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT @x = SUM(p.COG)
FROM Products p JOIN
     dbo.SplitStringIDsIntoTable(@ProductIDs, ',') ss
     ON p.ProductId = ss.ProductId;
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I do appreciate that, but I had to remove the (ProductID) then it worked. Otherwise I was getting:
Table-valued function 'SplitStringIDsIntoTable' cannot have a column alias.

Its working like this :
SELECT @x = SUM(p.COG)
FROM Products p JOIN
     dbo.SplitStringIDsIntoTable(@ProductIDs, ',') ss
     ON p.ProductId = ss.ProductId;

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list with duplicate IDs, `IN` will not DUPLICATE the results while `JOIN` will.  For example:

```
Declare @List varchar(50)='10,11,12,11,11'

-- Using IN Returns
Select count(*) 
 From  OD 
 Where [OD-Nr] IN (Select Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@List,','))

-- Using JOIN
Select count(*) 
From  [OD] A
Join  (Select Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@List,',')) B on (Key_Value=A.[OD-Nr])
```

Results

The IN returned 3 while JOIN returned 5